# Read Json array

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net

How can I Read the value of 'status' in this array using vb.net ?

```
{"message-count":1,
>> "messages":[{
>> "status":0,
>>"to":"XXXXXXXXX",
>>"client-ref":"",
>>"message-id":"030350003865BC53",
>>"message-price":"X.XXX",
>>"remaining-balance":X.XXX}
]}
```

Comment: What did you try? Do you know what JSON is?

Comment: yes. it's  JavaScript Object Notation. I'm trying to read this array using vb.net. array is coming from php script.

Comment: Ok then you know what JSON means... But what is JSON? What does the [ mean? Or the { ?

Comment: I was studying this link below. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942585/newtonsoft-json-jsonreaderexception 
but I have no idea how to read a single value like 'status'

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this code to work as you have it, you'll need to know that the object returned by DeserializeObject is a generic dictionary of string,object. Here's the code to do it that way:

```
     var json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var routes_list = (IDictionary<string, object>)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(
    "{\"message-count\":1,
    \"messages\":[{
    \"status\":0,
    \"to\":\"XXXXXXXXX\",
    \"client-ref\":\"\",
    \"message-id\":"030350003865BC53\",
    \"message-price":\"X.XXX\",
    \"remaining-balance\":X.XXX}
    ]}
    "

);
    Console.WriteLine(routes_list["test"]);
```

Comment: how can I use newtonsoftjson ?