# ElasticClient an error when checking the connection status

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to check the connection status, but there is an exception when checking.

```
var node = new Uri("http://myhost:9200");       
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);

ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);
IStatusResponse status = client.Status();
```

After calling client.Status() throws an exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

JSON integer 12500348306 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'indices.companyindx.index.primary_size_in_bytes', line 1, position 37862.

**If i do not check the status of call, then everything works fine**.

I'm using C # and Nest 1.0.0-beta1

What could be the reason?

Comment: I think the prob is port..try port no 9300..!

Comment: Unfortunately, on port 9300 data is not returned

Comment: Still it throwing exception???

Comment: Port 9300 just is not listening

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942585/newtonsoft-json-jsonreaderexception

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, I can not control the response from the server

Comment: IF you want solution pls post the rest of the code.. with your sample doc..!

Comment: About such a response. 
The error occurs before the index access

{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 36,
    "successful": 36,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "indices": {
    "companyindx": {
      "index": {
        "primary_size_in_bytes": 7472972168,
        "size_in_bytes": 22643123421
      }......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in NEST, more info [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/pull/660).  Should be fixed in the next release if that PR is merged.  Good find!